# Array return null for different SQL query filter types

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

I would like to ask help from you guys, i've been dealing a problem in which i'm having difficulty to resolve.

I have these two types of SQL:

```
SQL1: select id, description from table where description = '1234';
SQL2: select id, description from table where description = 'record-data';
```

both of the SQLs above are working fine when they are executed, below is there data type setup in the table:

```
id:integer, description:character varying(30)
```

now, i have records stored in the table where description field contains integer and string values.

here's the problem, when issuing a print_r to each SQL, SQL1 is blank while SQL2 returns array elements data/result

```
SQL1: Array()
SQL2: Array([0] => Array
(
        [id] => 9
        [0] => 9
        [description] => record-data
        [1] => record-data
)
```

both of these data(s) are existing in the table - i can't seem to understand the problem i encountered. Need your thoughts and help on this scenario.

BTW, I'm using PostgreSQL as my database.

Thanks!

Here's my php code / function:

```
private function getPrimIds($val){

$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=xxxx;host=x.x.x.x", xxx,xxx );

$sql = "select id, description from table where description = '$val'";
$exec = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$exec->execute();
$result = $exec->fetchAll();

print "<br>";
print_r($result);
die();

if(count($result) > 0){
    $pr_id = $result[0]["id"];
    }

    return $pr_id;
}
```

Comment: Can You share your php code?

Comment: @malutki5200 please see above, ive updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: This means that you don't have description `'1234'`. It can be `' 1234  '` or `'1234   '` or whatever. So check your table data again

Comment: @u_mulder im pretty sure it exists..no spaces

Comment: sql-engine tells you the opposite. If you not sure in php-code - run a query directly on `psql` in console or in pgAdmin

Comment: @u_mulder i did run it in pgadmin and its working fine as i said

Comment: So you copied `$sql` text and run in pgadmin?

Comment: @u_mulder both of these SQL1: select id, description from table where description = '1234';
SQL2: select id, description from table where description = 'record-data'; are working fine when executed in pgAdmin sql pane...the problem is in the php where i can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: Once again - are you sure that `$sql` value in your function is the same as `select id, description from table where description = '1234'`?

Comment: yes @u_mulder it is identically the same

Comment: what's the point of using prepared statements if you use string concatanation like that??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your function is ok. There must be a problem with the value you are looking for. 
Try changing:

> "select id, description from table where description = '$val'";

to:

```
"select id, description from table where description like '%$val%'";
```